# Looking for a level translator for single duplex serial bus

Tags: level-shifting

I have a 3.3V UART (two pins) plus a direction selector pin (also 3.3V.) I need to talk to and listen on a single duplex serial bus at 5V with 20 mA drive strength. The signaling rate is 3 Mbit/s, although switching directions is allowed to take 4 microseconds.
An automatic bidirectional translator like TXB0102 is not right because it ignores the direction signal.
A 74hct125 (one element going each way) doesn't do level translation.
A simple MOSFET for translation isn't good enough because it's not push/pull and thus doesn't get the drive strength both ways (plus strong pull-ups are bad for this bus.)
Finally, I prefer something in DIP-8 but can go up to DIP-14 if no external components are needed, and I'll break down and use SMDs if there is no other choice.

So, what existing component is there that fulfills these requirements? I've browsed parametric search at Digi-Key but not found anything that his all the requirements above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 74HCT125 is fine.  Power it with 5V and it will read your 3V3 Tx and enable signal just fine because \$V_{IH}\$ is only 1.6V (2V worst case).  For the 3V3 Rx use a resistive voltage divider for 'level translation' from the 74HCT125.

Comment: This is the closest I've come to a small, working solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need one driver ('125) for each direction of the bus:

- One with the input connected to the 5V bus, and the output connected to the 3.3V IC. For this, you could use a 74AHC125, or a 74LVC125, powered from 3.3V, as these tolerate the 5V input. 74HC125 is not okay, as it does not tolerate input above its V<sub>CC</sub>.
- One with the input connected to the 3.3V IC, and the output connected to the 5V bus. For this, you could use a 74HCT125, or a 74AHCT125, powered from 5V, as these have an input high threshold level of 2V, so they will correctly recognize the output of the 3.3V IC.

You'll also have to drive the output enable of these drivers so you'll need an inverter as well.

Answer (score 1):

What about the [Si865x](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/Si865x.pdf)? This device does not only translate the levels, it can does also isolate the to sides. I have used it several times and made positive experience.

Comment: The 51 and 52 could work, although RF based isolation seems like overkill/cost. I'll keep it in mind for when I really need that!